# Studio3T unable to connect with mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, database-connection, studio3t

Putting mongo connection string in studio3T first gave an error that url must be encoded. My username and password had colon and string had other special characters, so I did the Url encoding

But now after pasting the Url encoded string it keeps giving error unable to verify the text records.

Please help

Comment: What did you use for a connection string?

Comment: Would be helpful if you can provide screenshot that contains the connection strings you inputted (of course having sensitive information masked/blurred), and the exception message :)

Comment: Would be helpful if you can provide **the text** that contains the connection strings you inputted (of course having sensitive information masked), and the exception message :)

Comment: unable to verify text records sounds like a DNS failure - are you using mongodb+srv?